# How to set data in a c# class (multiple class)

Tags: c#

My class format:

```
public class StatusViewModel
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class SendCheckBillViewModel
{
    public StatusViewModel StatusViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<GetCheckBillViewModel> GetCheckBillViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class GetCheckBillViewModel
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is how to set value in c#. I have tried this pattern:

```cs
var v = new SendCheckBillViewModel(); 
v.StatusViewModel.StatusCode = 200;
v.StatusViewModel.Message = "";
v.GetCheckBillViewModel.AddRange(viewList);
```

But the value is not set in my `SendCheckBillViewModel` class.
Can anyone help explain to me why this approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to create instances of StatusViewModel and GetCheckBillViewModel before setting any value.

```
var v = new SendCheckBillViewModel(); 
 v.StatusViewModel = new StatusViewModel();
 v.GetCheckBillViewModel = new List<GetCheckBillViewModel>();

 v.StatusViewModel.StatusCode = 200;
 v.StatusViewModel.Message = "";
 v.GetCheckBillViewModel.AddRange(viewList);
```

Answer (score 0):

`StatusViewModel` and `GetCheckBillViewModel` are `class` and `List`, they need to be instanced/initiated. You can do it in-line

```
public class SendCheckBillViewModel
{
    public StatusViewModel StatusViewModel { get; set; } = new StatusViewModel();
    public List<GetCheckBillViewModel> GetCheckBillViewModel { get; set; } = new List<GetCheckBillViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: public StatusViewModel StatusViewModel { get; set; } = new StatusViewModel();
    public List<GetCheckBillViewModel> GetCheckBillViewModel { get; set; } = new List<GetCheckBillViewModel>();

Comment: Why use this pattern. can u brief me?

Comment: @MahfuzMorshed IMHO this is the cleanest way. You don't have to use it, you can do it in `SendCheckBillViewModel` constructor or like suggested in the other answer. But you do have to do the initialization somewhere.